# jQuery UI Dialog moves my DOM content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I had the problem that my [jquery ui dialog was only opening once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299083/jquery-ui-dialog-only-works-first-time),

So I tried this:

```
/* Prepare */
$('.steps > div.step-1 .bicicleta .attributos').dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true
});
            /* Trigger */
$('.steps > div.step-1 .bicicleta > .info > .img').on('click',function(){
            alert($(this).parents('.bicicleta').find('.attributos').length);
            $(this).parents('.bicicleta').find('.attributos').dialog('open');
});
```

the problem is that they can seem to find the .attributos class on the click event, I look into firebug and indeed, the content was moved next to the  into the UI dialog 's

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: When you call `.dialog` on an element (e.g. a div) that element moved to the end of `<body>` and wrapped inside a helper div. Can you explain a little what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well i want to be able of opening multiple times the dialog @SalmanA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.dialog({})` on a div, it is appended to the `body` element and wrapped inside a helper div. Since the div has moved, you can no longer locate that div using parent/sibling/children selectors.

One possible solution is to refer the dialogged div using IDs. Here is a rough outline:

```
var id = $('.steps > div.step-1 .bicicleta .attributos').uniqueId().attr('id');
$('#' + id).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});
$('.steps > div.step-1 .bicicleta > .info > .img').data('linked-dialog-id', id).on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('linked-dialog-id');
    $('#' + id).dialog("open");
});
```

The [uniqueId](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/) adds a unique id to the specified elements if necessary.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).uniqueId is not a function. Also, there are multiple `.attributos` elements, will that take care of it?

Comment: Requires a recent version of jQuery UI. You can write your own function instead. The pattern above should take care of multiple dialogged elements (use .each if necessary).

Comment: I see, well; I added the id in the server side and it works, thanks!

Comment: Adding ids (e.g. `<div id="step-1-dialog">` and `<img id="step-1-dialog-trigger">`) on server side is a better solution.